# How to get <iron-icons> to work in Polymer 2.x

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, iron-elements

#### Narrow Question

*By troubleshooting, I think I have narrowed my "larger problem" down to the following question. (But I could be wrong.):*

How do I properly download the latest version of `<iron-icons>` to my local machine?

By "latest version," I mean the version that is imported via the following:

```
<base href="//polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
<link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
```

The above version of importing `<iron-icons>` [works on my demo here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/pKnrlIbGhfQPFq10aAJS?p=preview)

However, when I do either of the following:

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/iron-icons

bower update --save
```

And try to import on my local server like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
```

it fails silently and I see no icons at all. But I do see extra space where the icons are supposed to render.

#### Bigger Question (the real problem I'm trying to solve)

I am trying to get my `<iron-icons>` to render properly in the browser.

#### What I expect to see

I expect to see a two `<iron-icon>` elements like this:

[image]

(anchored in between other test elements: `Hello World` and `<img>`)

#### What I actually see

No icons at all. But white space where they should render.

#### Steps to reproduce

Run

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/iron-icons
```

or, if `<iron-icons>` is already installed:

```
bower update --save
```

then

```
polyserve
```

or

```
polymer serve
```

#### Version

I believe I am using v2.0.1 of `<iron-icons>`. [Here is the entire contents of the bower.json file.](https://pastebin.com/raw/TT7e5TN8)

bower.json

```
"iron-icons": "PolymerElements/iron-icons#^2.0.1",
```

#### Configuration

OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Hardware: MacBook Air

Browser: Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

#### Demo

[Here is my Plunker demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/pKnrlIbGhfQPFq10aAJS?p=preview)

#### Code

The following code does render `<iron-icons>` as expected:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pKnrlIbGhfQPFq10aAJS?p=preview

```
<base href="//polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html">

<dom-module id="demo-el">
  <template>

    Hello world
    <iron-icon icon="add"></iron-icon>
    <iron-icon icon="favorite"></iron-icon>
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/400/200/" />

  </template>
  <script>
    class DemoEl extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'demo-el'
      }

      constructor() {
        super();
      }

    }
    customElements.define(DemoEl.is, DemoEl);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The following code does NOT render `<iron-icons>` as expected (served locally):

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">

<dom-module id="app-main">
  <template>

    Hello world
    <iron-icon icon="add"></iron-icon>
    <iron-icon icon="favorite"></iron-icon>
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/400/200/" />

  </template>
  <script>
    class AppMain extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'app-main'
      }

      constructor() {
        super();
      }

    }
    customElements.define(AppMain.is, AppMain);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

However, the above code does render `<iron-icons>` as expected when I do a direct substitution of:

```
<base href="//polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
<link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
```

for

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
```

## Edit

By comparing the text of the imported files using the CDN

```
<base href="//polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
<link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
```

and local imports:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
```

I discovered there is a discrepancy in the imported version of the `iron-iconset-svg.html` file. My bower.json file says the dependent version is `"iron-iconset-svg": "1 - 2"` or `"iron-iconset-svg": "polymerelements/iron-iconset-svg#^2.0.0"` but the bower.json file here says the dependent version is `"iron-iconset-svg": "polymerelements/iron-iconset-svg#^1.0.0"`

So, now the question appears to reduce to how do I get the local version of `iron-icons.html` to import the same version of `iron-iconset-svg.html` as the online CDN import version.

### Edit 2

The problem persists when I just copy the `iron-iconset-svg.html` file from the CDN and paste it into my local file system. So, apparently something else is going on too.

### Edit 3

[I followed the instructions here for upgrading to Polymer 2.0:](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#update-bower-dependencies)

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#update-bower-dependencies

> 1. Remove the existing bower_components folder.

```
rm -rf bower_components
```

> 2. Update the Polymer version in bower.json to the latest versions.

```
Component            | Version
---------------------|--------
Polymer              | ^2.0.0
webcomponentsjs      | ^1.0.0
web-component-tester | ^6.0.0
Polymer elements     | ^2.0.0
```

> 3. Install the new dependencies.

```
bower install
```

This did not solve the problem. However I could not update `Polymer elements` to `^2.0.0`

bower.json

```
"dependencies" : {
  ...
  "polymer-elements" : "^2.0.0",
  ...
}
```

caused an error and so did:

bower.json

```
"dependencies" : {
  ...
  "polymerelements" : "^2.0.0",
  ...
}
```

and so did:

bower.json

```
"dependencies" : {
  ...
  "PolymerElements" : "^2.0.0",
  ...
}
```

Comment: What version of iron-icons is installed in your local project?

Comment: @Ofisora: I believe its v2.0.1. bower.json: `"iron-icons": "PolymerElements/iron-icons#^2.0.1",`  [Here is the entire bower.json file.]("iron-icons": "PolymerElements/iron-icons#^2.0.1",)

Comment: Your link for  entire content of `bower.json` does not work.

Comment: @Ofisora: I believe it's v2.0.1. bower.json: "iron-icons": "PolymerElements/iron-icons#^2.0.1", [Here is the entire bower.json file.](https://pastebin.com/raw/TT7e5TN8) ... https://pastebin.com/raw/TT7e5TN8

Comment: @Ofisora: Please read the **Edit** section I just added. I have made some progress and think I have isolated the problem to the importation of the `iron-iconset-svg.html` file by the `iron-icons.html` file.

Comment: This works for me. Why don't you give a try deleting everything in resolutions and do `bower install` again.

Comment: @Ofisora: The suggestion you made made sense. [It's also what Polymer recommends here.](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#update-bower-dependencies) I described my procedure and results in detail with **Edit 3**. Please take a look and share any ideas you might have what I might try next. I'm stumped.

Comment: I think it should be `polymer` only. Also, you can install any component pointing the certain version like `bower install --save PolymerElements/iron-icons#2.0.1`. One more thing some times some other element also needs to be updated. In my case I had to update `iron-selector` first time and `iron-meta`  second time when the icon didn't showed up. When installing you might get to choose version of different of that element. You can choose the latest one.

Comment: @Mowzer, man.. sometimes the problem is so small.. you make too much edit, I would delete everything (even bower cache), and run the install again, You are using Chrome so there is no reason it shouldn't. If you are using Firefox, first you need webcomponents polyfill. You try to import the polyfill after actually trying to import custom elements, which absolutely make no sense, and you should use <script> tag for the polyfill because this is a `js` file !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution proposed by @Ofisora in the comments works for me—update `iron-selector` and `iron-meta`:

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/iron-meta
bower install --save PolymerElements/iron-selector
```

Comment: Note to future readers: I selected the latest version option for both updates. Also, clearing out bower and running a global `bower install` DID NOT work. But this solution did.

Answer (score 1):

> `iron-icons` is a utility import that includes the definition for the
>   `iron-icon` element, `iron-iconset-svg` element, as well as an import
>   for the default icon set.

This means that `iron-icons` is directly dependent on both `iron-icon` and `iron-iconset-svg`. And both `iron-icon` and `iron-iconset-svg` element depends on `iron-meta`.

When you update `iron-icons` to the latest version, these elements `iron-icon`, `iron-iconset-svg` and `iron-meta` might not get updated since you will get all these components by default. So, updating `iron-meta` is one of the solution.

---

Also, when you install or update element in polymer you will see messages like:

> Unable to find a suitable version for iron-icons, please choose one by
>   typing one of the numbers below:

Always choose the suitable or latest version depending on other element you have.

When finished updating or installing you will see a note like:

```
Please note that,
    iron-iconset-svg#a47e824859 depends on iron-meta#2.0-preview which resolved to iron-meta#7404b31da3
    iron-icon#1.0.13, iron-icon#1.0.13, iron-icon#1.0.13, iron-iconset-svg#1.1.2, iron-iconset-svg#1.1.2 depends on iron-meta#^1.0.0 which resolved to iron-meta#1.1.3
    iron-icon#2.0.0, iron-iconset-svg#2.0.0 depends on iron-meta#1 - 2 which resolved to iron-meta#2.0.2
```

Make sure you read this and install/update dependencies required.

---

Note: In my case I had to update `iron-selector` as well since I was using `iron-icon` inside the `iron-selector`.